# Changing integration bounds

Tags: calculus, integration

I came accross this line:
$$x\in [0,1],y\in [0,1]$$
$$E(Y|x)=\int_y y*g(y|x)dx=\int _0^1y*g(y|x)dy$$
Can someone please explain how the second equality holds! Thanks.

Comment: I think actually maybe it is a typo and the first dx should be dy